# Int64 и double кто длиннее?

Tags: c#, .net, double, int

На днях задался интересным вопросом, как так получается, что в тип double можно запихнуть число с 300 знаками, а в Int64 всего 20 знаков?

оба типа данных занимают в памяти по 8 байт

[image: типы данных]

Comment: `Int64` и `Double` содержат одинаковое количество информации, так как оба имеют вес 8 байт.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что число в `int` хранится всегда точно, а в `double` - с погрешностью, причем при росте экспоненты, погрешность растет (*что неудивительно*, растет экспоненциально).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, на деле, в числах с плавающей запятой хранятся не все знаки числа, а лишь первые несколько штук, и дополнительно хранится номер места среди этих знаков, где нужно поставить десятичный разделитель.

Comment: т.е на деле в дабле хранится 15-17 знаков ,как указано в таблице? тогда зачем они пишут о +-1.7 *10 ** 308   ?

Comment: @Men пишут про диапазон значений, а не про что в 8 байт влезет "Война и Мир".

Comment: Тогда что означает приблизительный диапазон значений?

Comment: @Men я у 5 символах могу поместить число "1e100", но это не значит что я в 5 символах могу точно описать любое целое число от 0 до 1e100